# VS code shows errors before saving

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

when I am typing in vs code it shows error even before saving.
I am coding in python an every time I start to type something it just become red
its getting really annoying to type.
ex when I start to type a function just after typing def it becomes red.
I felt maybe its because of linting I tried disabled all the linting extensions but it still remains
I even reinstalled vs code bunch of times.
What can be the cause of it?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have pylint? What happens when you hover the red squiggles? What do those tooltips say?

Comment: yes I disabled every linter, its says syntax error but those should pop up after i save,it wont work with LintOnSave ,either change in setting is not reflecting or it is something else entirely

Comment: @Dev -Could you please provide us with complete information when the mouse is hovering? Usually, its provider will be displayed in the mouse hovering information. In addition, when the code is not completely edited, not only Linting will display a warning, but the python language service will also display a warning message.